Is there a way to add log.origin... in default Elastic as not nested?
I am trying to add log.origin values to my json when logging. I am using default Elastic encoder co.elastic.logging.logback.EcsEncoder. I've successfully added it using <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>, but I would like to add it as new fields. This options adds it as nested object.
here is my logback appender
<appender name="ELASTIC_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoder class="co.elastic.logging.logback.EcsEncoder">
      <serviceName>My_service</serviceName>
      <includeOrigin>true</includeOrigin>
    </encoder>
    <additionalField>
      <key>UUID</key>
      <value>String</value>
    </additionalField>

    <file>${LOGS}/log.3</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/log.3.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
      <maxFileSize>${LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE:-10MB}</maxFileSize>
      <maxHistory>${LOG_FILE_MAX_HISTORY:-0}</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>

And here is the json that I get
{
  "@timestamp": "2024-04-24T11:00:06.475Z",
  "log.level": "WARN",
  "message": "Mesg",
  "ecs.version": "1.2.0",
  "service.name": "My_service",
  "event.dataset": "My_service",
  "process.thread.name": "main",
  "log.logger": "com.example",
  "UUID": "UUID",
  "log": {
    "origin": {
      "file": {
        "name": "Test.java",
        "line": 130
      },
      "function": "getPerson"
    }
  }
}

